# Integrating a electrode component in to app

Tags: reactjs, walmart-electrode

I have created an electrode component using the archetype 'yo electrode:component' let's call it ptd-product-tile(the component class is named 'PtdProductTile'. I also created and an application using 'yo electrode' let's call it ptd-frame. I published my component to npm repository and added it to the dependencies in package.json of my application. When I try to import the component in to 'frame/src/client/components/home.jsx' using the below line I see an error.

```
import { PtdProductTile } from 'ptd-product-tile';
```

the error I see is here

```
./src/client/components/home.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ptd-product-tile' in '/Users/xyz/code/frame/src/client/components'
@ ./src/client/components/home.jsx 35:22-49
@ ./src/client/routes.jsx
@ ./src/client/app.jsx
@ multi (webpack)
```

I see the component is downloaded in to node_modules in the application but I don't know how I can use in the application. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example Electrode application, as generated and unmodified, except the changes to add an Electrode component.

The component itself is also as generated and unmodified.

- app: https://github.com/electrode-io/electrode-demo-app
- component: https://github.com/electrode-io/electrode-demo-component
- published: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electrode-demo-component
- commit to app to use the component: https://github.com/electrode-io/electrode-demo-app/commit/e320050c2c1ae8f0f5876c2ec2d972ef31a901a9

I hope this helps.